# Outputting resources generated by for_each in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, list, terraform, output

I am creating S3 buckets from an array like so:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "aws_s3_zenity_bucket" {
  bucket = "${each.value}"
  for_each = toset(var.s3_buckets)
}
```

where `s3_buckets` is just a list with s3 buckets names I want to create.

I want to module to output a list that contains all the ARNs of the generated buckets.

pseudo-code of what I want:

```
output "s3_buckets_arns" {
    for_each = aws_s3_bucket.aws_s3_zenity_bucket
    select_as_output = each.value.arn
} # should look something like ["arn1", "arn2", ....]
```

How do I do that in TF?

Comment: Something like `value = [for bucket in aws_s3_bucket.aws_s3_zenity_bucket: bucket.arn]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`splat`](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/splat) operator combined with the [`values`](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/values) function:

```
output "s3_buckets_arns" {
  value = values(aws_s3_bucket.aws_s3_zenity_bucket)[*].arn
}
```